# Device to train abs while sitting

Tags: workout, abdominals

I was looking today and I saw that there is a device to train abs without exercising. I'd like to know if should I buy something like this to strengthen and define my abs? I have a normal body fat value with little visible abs. Is a good idea to buy this? I am just sitting in a chair and this is doing like "massage", will this help to define my abs?

Comment: Nope, don't buy this crap, it's not working

Comment: Principes there is the same as in EMS training. EMS came from therapy for paralized people, to force their muscles to find out how to work by stimulate'em by electricity, so in this way it really useful. But if you expect some hyperthrophy and (whats most important here) losing fat on your belly - it would not work

Comment: Seriously? gtfooh

Answer (score 1):

## Exercise Rule #1

#### If you're not moving your not exercising!

This is also called the **Rule of Inertia**

When was the last time you sat in a chair, strapped a machine to yourself and then magically received a Million dollars...?

If recently, then yes I highly recommend you buy the device.

Otherwise despite what anyone trying to sell you something might say, **Rule #1** holds true.

There is no mythical device that can lower your belly fat and give you killer abs (or a million dollars).

Instead invest your money in a competent personal trainer or home video workout program. (My suggestion as a competent personal trainer would be the [AthleanX](https://athleanx.com/) Programs)